# Elastic Search: Ordering based on custom logic

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I am giving a pattern "Master Servant" to elastic server search api.
It returns all the documents that contain at least one of them (Master OR Servant).

It shows the results in descending order of score.
However, I want to change that ordering to my custom logic i.e If a document contains both the words i.e. Master AND Servant, show that document first.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: You are thinking about this in the wrong way. You should consider ways of scoring **higher** if the all the terms match ;-).

Comment: My requirement is that if a document contains both the terms then it should be the most relevant or with the highest score

Comment: Exactly what I said :-).

Comment: "Should consider ways of scoring higher"...that means for my scenario, if my document has both the words, it  should have a high score. How can I implement the same. By default , ES will use algorithms like TF/INF to calculate score. But I want to force my logic for the score to be calculated.

Comment: The default (TF/IDF) score from the `match` query is as you are asking.  Documents with both "Master" and "Servant" will score higher than documents with only one matching term.  If you are seeing different behavior please post your query results with `explain: true`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `bool` query.

From the ['ES definitive Guide'](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/multi-query-strings.html)

> The bool query takes a more-matches-is-better approach, so the score from each match clause will be added together to provide the final _score for each document. Documents that match both clauses will score higher than documents that match just one clause.

**EDIT** Based on comment:

to clarify I believe you want something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "field": "Master" }},
        { "match": { "field": "Servant"   }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup I can use a bool query that will have only one condition , say...
say:match=>{text=>"Master Servant"}
So this query will also contain the documents that have both Master and Servant. I want them to be on top